# Is there a requirement for a someone to say the Amidah together with the congregation in a shul when there is no minyan?

Tags: shemoneh-esrei, synagogue

I recall reading in O.C. that there is a requirement (or is it a "preference"?) for an individual to pray the silent Amidah together with the congregation in a synagogue.

Is this requirement applicable only when there is a minyan, or would it apply if you are in a synagogue without a minyan present?

Answer (score 2):

The [Kitzur Shulchan Aruch (12:9)](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Kitzur_Shulchan_Aruch.12.9?with=all&lang=bi) brings that "It is a great *mitzvah* to pray in a synagogue or in a *Beis Midrash* because these are sacred places. Even if it happens that there is no *minyan,* it is nevertheless a *mitzvah* to pray there even when praying alone, because these are holy places".

It is certainly debatable whether *"lehitpalel"* ("pray") in this case refers specifically to *Shemoneh Esrei,* but even as a broad guideline for all prayer it seems it would apply to the *Amidah.*

I assume ""*Even without a minyan*" to mean praying with a *minyan* is preferable to less than a *minyan,* and "*even alone*" to mean praying with fewer than nine other men is preferable to praying alone.

Comment: I dared to change a few strange transliterations, please roll back if you don't like them.